# Is there a way to stop people cloning certain users in perforce?

Tags: perforce

I don't expect so... background, common sense didn't prevail and an admin cloned a perforce superuser to make an account for a new starter :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to stop a specific super-user from creating more super-users is to implement a form-in trigger on the protections table, rejecting updates by untrusted super-users when they add more entries with super permission.

That said, if you need separation between user management and Perforce administration, you could configure your server to authenticate against an LDAP (or Active Directory) server, and perform all the user management there.